# C# multiprocess-multithread service and windows scheduler

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, process, scheduler

I have developed a windows service that, shortly, manages thousand of remote devices.
Currently it consists of two precesses, each with some hundreds of threads (we can discuss about of the opportunity to reduce the number of threads, but this is not the point), and all works quite fine.
Now I am trying to join all threads in a single process to semplify data exchange between threads, but what happens is that now all threads runs slower (it seems like in some conditions some threads run much less frequently).
So my question is: it is expected that windows scheduler works in different way on a single-process/multi-thread application compared to a multi-process/multi-thread application?

Little simple example:
- single core CPU
- 2 threads (A and B)
- thread A is doing a very long task, while thread B is sleeping
- now is time to wake up thread B, but thread A is still running

My conjecture:
- on single-process/multi-thread, scheduler force thread B to sleep and delay its wake up
- on multi-process/multi-thread, if A belongs to process 1 and B belongs to process 2, scheduler wake up thread B when expected

Could be?
Any suggestion to join all threads in a single process without throubles?

Sorry for my poor English.

**EDIT**
Following the advice of Luaan I am profiling application to check GC behavior. This is what I see on a 45 seconds time slot:
[image]
Some questions:
- why 13.000.000ms here?
- why reference to sleep here?

**EDIT 2**
Finally I solved my performance issue: as I said I was using some hundreds of threads in my service. I have rewritten some parts of the code in order to group old threads in few main threads and now I am using 8 main worker thread that do most of the job (around 50 threads total including secondary threads)... and magically now the service runs using something like half of the cpu.
Maybe the issue was related to GC activity also, but I think that most of the issues was due to the overhead of context switch for my threads.

**EDIT 3**
As some little performance issues continues I checked GC load with a PerformanceCounter object and you are right: my threads hangs when GC use about 99% of cpu time. How can I solve? Now I am trying to set GC in server mode.

Comment: There's not nearly enough information in your question to help much. Are you messing with thread/process priorities? Is one of the "services" a GUI application? Are you doing blocking I/O or non-blocking I/O? What synchronization are you using between the threads? What signalling? How does the GC come into this (remember, joining the processes means joining their GCs)? What does a concurrency profiler tell you? Also, single-core CPUs behave *very* differently in multi-threading - Windows tries to minimize context switch overhead, so it doesn't schedule as aggressively as on multi-cores.

Comment: I try to provide more informations: I am not managing thread priority; no GUI, just a windows service; I am doing blocking operation to a SQL Server on lot of threads; I am not managing thread synchronization, each thread do its job and I exchange data between threads asynchronously; I am not forcing GC in some way, but really I see with a profiler that GC do "a lot" of job. Finally, real server is not single core but has 4 cores. Thank you.

Comment: Basically it seems like threads that perform I/O to SQL Server are blocking thread that perform communications to devices. This do not happens if threads are on different processes.

Comment: Well, if GC gets a lot of work in your process, it might very well be the cause of the slowdown. Two processes means two separate managed memory spaces with their own GCs. In particular, if one of the processes is a lot more memory-heavy, joining them would make the other process much slower. When you profile the service, does it seem the GC pauses might be in the right ballpark to explain the slowdown?

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I am going to check again with profiler. Sorry, but I can'y understand your question ("When you profile the service, does it seem the GC pauses might be in the right ballpark to explain the slowdown?"). What do I need exactly to check?

Comment: Look how often the GC happens and how long it takes. It might very well be that your "device threads" are blocked by the GC, rather than the "SQL threads".

Comment: Please check my edit on OP.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, CPU cores and threading are unrelated. The Kernel decides how a thread is divided up amongst logical CPUs. The lower the logical CPUs the more context switching has to occur, slowing the process down overall, but it's still multi-threaded.

If you want to talk to other threads then the normal procedure is to do this with events which are subscribed to by the main application thread. You can then decide what to do with this information.

You shouldn't be concerned with how the kernel divides up the threads over logical CPUs as it does this automatically unless you are specifically using a processor affinity mask.

Comment: Hi, thank you, I agree with you. But what is your opinion on my problem ("what happens is that now all threads runs slower")?